# What is the correct way to type cast a dynamic SObject?

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, compile-error, typecast

I'm trying to get the object type conversion as below. But getting compiler error saying Invalid Type t. Any clue to correct it. Thanks. obj_Name is String and Formobject is SObject.

```
        Type t = Type.forName(obj_name);
        return (t) FormObject;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast to a Type that way. We do not have "templates" in our language, so we cannot generate multiple methods from a single source. Simply cast to an SObject, and it will work in most cases.

```
SObject FormObject = (SObject)Type.forName(obj_name).newInstance();
return FormObject;
```

You'll still have to cast again to get the SObject into a concrete type. Here's an example you can run in Execute Anonymous:

```
SObject rec = (SObject)Type.forName('Account').newInstance();
Account a = (Account)rec;
```

The callee will be responsible for casting the object back in to the desired type.

In Java, we can do something like this:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    T buildSomething() {
        T x = new T();
        return x;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work in Apex Code, because we don't have parameterization of classes. This is something that previously existed in Apex Code, but was pulled for some unknown reason.

Comment: I'm storing a Contact in SObject, similarly I need SObject as a Contact object, that's why this is done. And apparently this SObject has to store Objects dynamically, therefore need to cast it this manner. Couldn't help it though.

Comment: @PasanEeriyagama You can't specifically instantiate an SObject. You can create a record of a specific type and store it in an SObject, but you can't literally make an SObject.

Comment: Wonder why when we have a Type class, and we can't use it for casting in SF. It only allows to create new instances.

Comment: @PasanEeriyagama Type gives us the ability to make classes dynamically at runtime. It's not as useful as a Reflection class, but it's better than always requiring static type references.

Comment: So is it not possible to cast SObject with values to a specific Object such as Contact, Lead dynamically? I know this is possible by hard coding (Contact), (Lead), etc..

Comment: @PasanEeriyagama Yeah, like I said, the callee has to do the casting. We still have get/put, getSObject/putSObject, and getSObjects that we can use on the generic SObject type to get and set values, so casting isn't always necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

```
return (task) FormObject;
```

instead of object instance you need to pass object API name.